# Renaming IIS Website names

Tags: iis, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm wanting to rename some websites in IIS for organization purposes. I assume that the name is just meta data and won't cause any errors or problems but I'm not sure. Is there anything that relies on the website name to be unchanged? SSL certs maybe? I know each site has an id in the meta base and I assume that is all that's needed to identify the site programmaticly.

Answer (score 1):

I often find when renaming sites in IIS 7 (Server 2008) that the server needs an iisreset as a 500 error occurs, or at the very least I have to close/re-open the IIS GUI. However, I've never encountered issues with SSL certificates after renaming a site.